Replace sequence of tuple value from another
val x = seq((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'))  
val y = seq((1, 'AA'), (3, 'CC'), (4, 'DD'))

Expected result
val z = seq((1, 'AA'), (2, 'b'))    

I can do it as below
x.toMap.map(k => (k._1, y.toMap.getOrElse(k._1, k._2))

But this will not preserve the order
Is there a way to do an ordered replacement

You want to replace the values of x by their lookup on y or leave them unchanged if they don't exists, right?

First, your code would work the same without the first toMap, which is not doing anything useful and is the one that is destroying the order.
Second, you are converting y to a Map for each element of x, making this really expensive and even worse that just using find or collectFirst.
Third, we could use some pattern matching to make the code a little bit more readable.
// If you have a better name, feel free to change it.
def lookupOrPreserve[K, V](
  input: Seq[(K, V)],
  lookup: Map[K, V]
): Seq[(K, V)] =
  input.map { case (key, originalValue) =>
    key -> lookup.getOrElse(key, default = originalValue)
  }

val x = seq((1 -> 'a'), (2 -> 'b'))  
val y = seq((1 -> 'AA'), (3 -> 'CC'), (4 -> 'DD'))
val z = lookupOrPreserve(input = x, lookup = y.toMap)


You need to clarify some of the constraints and what you tried and didn't work.
Assuming you want to transform x in one pass you could make a lookup Map from y.
A way of building a Map from what you have is
val lookup: Map[Int, String] = {
  val builder =
    Map.newBuilder[Int, String]

  for((key, value) <- y)
    builder += (key -> value)

  builder.result()
}

Then use the lookup to transform x elements that have correspondence.
